# Compile errors FreeImage on C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, freeimage

I keep receiving several error messages (currently 35) when I try to compile FreeImageNET C# wrapper. All the messages are in the same format.

Actually I've found that this question has been asked before, and the answer was to change "typeparamref" to "paramref". However, the rest of the error messages includes "paramref" already, so I do not know what to change to correct these errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Two of the error messages are as follows:

```
Error   1   Warning as Error: XML comment on 'FreeImageAPI.Palette.Palette(FreeImageAPI.Metadata.MetadataTag)' has a paramref tag for 'dib', but there is no parameter by that name D:\[kur]\[csharp]\image_tools\FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Library\Classes\Palette.cs 70  63  Library


Error   2   Warning as Error: XML comment on 'FreeImageAPI.Metadata.GifInformation.CreateGlobalPalette(int)' has a paramref tag for 'palette', but there is no parameter by that name   D:\[kur]\[csharp]\image_tools\FreeImage\Wrapper\FreeImage.NET\cs\Library\Classes\GifInformation.cs  76  23  Library
```

Comment: You can just disable "treat warnings as errors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, there's an XML comment on a method that describes parameters which do not exist. Besides not treating warnings as errors, another solution would be to not have Visual Studio create the XML documentation (this can be found on the "Build" tab of the project's settings).

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, disabling XML documentation creation solved the problem

Comment: Glad to hear. Then don't forget to mark my answer as accepted solution and maybe give it an upvote, too :-)

Comment: Well, I marked your answer as accepted solution, but I cannot give it an up vote as my reputation point is below 15 :(